# Expository accounts of the Thurston norm

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Other than Thurston's original paper (which I find quite hard to read), are there any expositions of the basic properties of the Thurston norm?  In particular, I'm interested in a proof of his characterization of which homology classes can be represented by fibers.  Some parts of this can be found in Kapovich's book, but he does not discuss the result I alluded to in my previous sentence.

Comment: You could have a look at Chapter 10 of Candel Conlon, Foliations II.
http://books.google.com/books?id=-B-QSWnbLUoC&lpg=PA58&dq=candel%20conlon%20foliations%20II&pg=PA325#v=onepage&q=thurston%20norm&f=false

Comment: Give a look also to Calegari - Foliations and the geometry of 3-manifolds.

Comment: Actually, I think Thurston's paper IS the canonical reference, because most people find it quite well-written.